# ExtJS 4 - Json Writer does not have Record config like Json Reader does

Tags: json, cakephp, extjs, extjs4, cakephp-2.1

Ok guys, working ExtJS4 and I have pretty much the exact opposite problem this guy did:
[How do I get an ExtJS JsonStore to put the JSON data directly into the request body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925751/how-do-i-get-an-extjs-jsonstore-to-put-the-json-data-directly-into-the-request-b)

In my application I have a nested data structure being loaded with associated models.

CakePHP in the backend expects (in pseudocode) the following format in saves:

```
[
  {
    [Model]
      [Field1]: [Value1],
      [Field2]: [Value2],
      [Field3]: [Value3]
  },
  {
    [Model]
      [Field1]: [Value1],
      [Field2]: [Value2],
      [Field3]: [Value3]
  }
]
```

This is what ExtJS is currently sending to the server:

```
[
  {
    [Field1]: [Value1],
    [Field2]: [Value2],
    [Field3]: [Value3],
    [Model] : null
  }
]
```

So, for some reason it's including the model as a null value and putting the parameters in the root node of the Json object.

The server sends the data to the client in a similar fashion but the Json Reader for the Json Proxy has a record parameter ([See here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Json-cfg-record)). Unfortunately the Json Writer has no such property (not even undocumented as I have tried setting it).

Currently my workaround on the back end is:
`$json = Set::insert($json, 'Model', $json);`
But it would be good if there was a better way to accomplish this.

**Update:**
To further expand, I am loading one store which loads nested Json data that automatically populates associated models in the client. (This is all done with Extjs methods without any custom code).

I have tried the root property in the Json writer but unforunatly with batch records it formats the request like this:

```
{
  [Root] : [
    {
      [Field1]: [Value1],
      [Field2]: [Value2],
      [Field3]: [Value3],
      [Model] : null
    },
    {
      [Field1]: [Value1],
      [Field2]: [Value2],
      [Field3]: [Value3],
      [Model] : null
    }
  ]
}
```

I have also tried Bancha (http://banchaproject.org) but I was unable to get that to work with Sencha Architect (which is being used for this project) and the solution they have provided at the moment was a "workaround" (which I was unable to get working).

Thank you,
-T6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing with the modelName:null looks like you have some custom code already here. To just get the data in a named object, the Writer has a property 'root' in ExtJS and 'rootProperty' in Sencha Touch, this could help.

There's also a framework which does all of this marshaling for you, see banchaproject.org
It costs a bit, similar to ExtJS, but it will do a lot of this work for you.

Comment: Hmm, I haven't written anything custom really. The only difference is that all my data is being loaded from one ajax call to multiple models/stores through Extjs model associations. I have tried the root property but that doesn't work quite right when the client syncs batch records. As all the records are under the root node. Now, in regards to Bancha, it is actually the first thing I looked at and was the reason I used CakePHP. Unfortunately it seems like it is not compatible with Sencha architect which this project is built with.

Comment: Was tinkering some more and found out that you are completely right about the Model: null. It seems that I had set the associationKey property in my HasManyAssociation. This had the Json reader trying to read from that node in the Json, and when not finding anything just setting it to null. Going to try Bancha again now that I have more familiarity with both software than I did when I first gave it a whirl.

Comment: Sadly Sencha Architect doesn't allow any configuration or enhancement, but Bancha works together with Sencha Architect (only the inline previews of lists and grids don't work if you are using the Bancha-build models). Check out http://banchaproject.org/using-sencha-architect-2.html for how to use them together.

Comment: PS: We now provide a much smoother integration with Sencha Architect!

Answer (score 0):

In cases where I've needed to customize the format in which the Writer sends the request, I"ve simply created my own custom writer (extending Ext.data.writer.Json), and have overwritten the writeRecords() method with whatever logic I needed to format the request correctly.

Comment: That is the route I will go if there is no other solution. The thing that really confuses me is that the Json Writer knows of the model name and makes a null node with the model name when it outputs. It's just not putting any of the fields in that node.